# jQuery cookie value as an AJAX response variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables

I have currency codes stored in a cookie. This values look like (EUR, USD, GBP, THB...)
I do an AJAX request to a free API (exchangeratesapi.io), where I want to convert a certain amount of THB (Thai Baht), to any currency a user has set in his cookie.

```
    // Set currency cookie to GBP
    $.cookie("Currency", "GBP");

    // AJAX request to exchangeratesapi
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=THB",
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        // Set cookie value to var "tocur"
        var tocur = $.cookie("Currency");
        // Get exchange rate for GBP and store it in var "exchangerate" 
        var exchangerate = (data.rates.tocur);
        // Amount of THB to be exchanged to GBP
        var amount = 250;
        // Result for THB amount * exchangerate
        var sum = (amount * exchangerate);
        // Insert result into HTML element, roundet to 2 decimals, replace "." with ","
        $('#responsedata').html(amount + " THB = " + sum.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + " " + tocur);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "Could not fetch exchange rates" );
    });
```

This works fine, as long as I set the variable "exchangerate" manually to (data.rates.GBP). As soon as I try to set it to (data.rates.tocur), I get NaN as a result.

Am I missing something? How can I get the cookie value stored in var "tocur" to work in my var exchangerate? Do I need to parse it somehow? Thank you very much in advance!

I've put it in a JS-Fiddle also: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/phii/72amuyLk/)

Comment: `data.rates.tocur` means you're trying to access a property named `"tocur"` inside the `rates` object; you want `data.rates[tocur]` instead. Try using `console.log(tocur)` or `debugger` for troubleshooting.

Comment: @user7290573 Thank you so much. I was thinking I had some CORS error and the cookies value isn't passed to the varible, I totally overlooked the syntax error for a whole day. Damn. Thanks a lot once again!